# Copy Cards including checklist in Trello

Tags: trello

Is there a way to copy a Card (project) in Trello including the checklist that it includes?

Comment: This would be an awesome feature - there are many repetative tasks in projects, and it would be nice to have card "templates" that I could copy

Comment: Update from 2013 - you can copy cards! http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44639/trouble-copying-cards

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the card go to **"More Actions..."**

[image]

Then Click on **Copy**

[image]

You can change the card description, if desired, and click Add

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chrome plugin that does that in the Chrome store. It needs a really simple patch which is at https://github.com/oo7ph/Trello-Clone/pull/7/files (see the Chrome store comments) to cater for recent updates to the Trello DOM.